# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 1, 25) for Tensor 'Placeholder_24:0', which has shape '(?, 25)'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm not sure how to reshape my Tensor to be (1, 25) instead of (1, 1, 25). I coded this in Python. I think it's reshape, but can't quite get it.

Answer (score 1):

> The [`reshape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape) method is for this purpose.

Try `reshape(you_tensor, [-1, 25])`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tf.squeeze](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/squeeze):

`tf.squeeze(your_tensor, axis=1)`